# data is not shown in vue js component after getting request

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

**hello. after clicking on gallery component this component would be shown and get request in methods but wouldn't show gallery data :(**


I wasn't having problem like this last time. maybe that's because my component is look like modal .
I know my talking is ridiculous :/

```
<template>
    <section class="ShowGallery">
        <div class="panelGallery">
            <div class="topBlock">
                <div class="close" @click="$emit('btnCloseGallery')"><i class="icon-error"></i></div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottomBlock">
                <div class="block first">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img :src="gallery.url">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="block second">
                    <h3>info gallery</h3>
                    {{gallery}}
                    <ul class="listInfo">
                        <li><span>{{gallery.size}}</span><span> : size </span></li>
                        <li><span v-text="gallery.type"></span><span> : format  </span></li>
                        <li><span v-text="gallery.resolution"></span><span> : resolution </span></li>
                        <li><span v-text="gallery.name"></span><span> : name  </span></li>
                        <li><span v-text="gallery.url"></span><span> : url  </span></li>
                        <li><span v-text="gallery.path"></span><span> : path  </span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props : ['gallery_id'],
        name: "ShowGallery",
        data(){
            return {
               gallery : {} ,
            }
        },
        methods : {
            async getGallery(){
                const data = await axios.get(`/admin/gallery/${this.gallery_id}`);
                this.gallery = data.data;
                console.log(this.gallery)
            }
        },
         mounted(){
             this.getGallery();
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you be a little more precise about what exactly is and isn't happening? e.g. Is the following an accurate description of what you're seeing? 1. The component initially shows with empty values, as expected. 2. The GET request can be seen in the Network tab of the developer tools and succeeds. 3. The console logging in `getGallery` logs the appropriate object to the console. 4. The component does not show the new values and remains empty, which is not expected.

Comment: The gallery component is hidden at first and is displayed after clicking the button and a request for gallery information is sent and stored in gallery information after download . the data is received but it is not displayed